# Can I launch Everything without getting UAC popup on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uac, launchy, everything

I like to use [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), and on XP I can use it to quickly start a new instance of [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) so I can find some file or other.  However on windows 7 when I try and start it from launchy I always get the UAC panel before it starts.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Everything FAQ](http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#How_do_I_bypass_the_UAC_to_run__Everything__with_administrative_privileges_on_system_startup) links to an article explaining how to [bypass UAC on Vista](http://blogs.techrepublic.com/window-on-windows/?p=730) using a shortcut. I'm not using Windows 7 at the moment so I can't test it, but I presume a similar process will work.

After that, make sure you use the correct shortcut from Launchy.

Comment: Also, launch the application with administrative rights. (Right-click on it and then hit: Run as admin)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Everything FAQ, starting *Everything* with the Windows Task Scheduler  works in *Launchy*, but you can’t input your search term in *Everything* via *Launchy*.

In my opinon, you have to live with the Windows 7 UAC if you want to benefit from searching your files with *Everything* via Launchy.

Alternately, you can disable the UAC in Windows 7 and live with lesser security on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Everything Search Startup UAC Bypass in Windows 7 & Windows 8 & Vista

http://mycoolfundas.blogspot.in/2013/05/everything-search-startup-uac-bypass-in.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

To turn UAC off in Vista, hold sown the Windows key and press R on the keyboard.
In the box that appears, type msconfig and click OK or press the return key.
A box will open with several tabs. The tab on the far right is the one you want.
Scroll down the list until you see a setting (and you have to read carefully) that offers to disable UAC. Click it once, the click the Launch button at the bottom of the window.
A Command Prompt box will flash open. Type exit to close it.
Reboot the machine. UAC is now off, but you will get warnings from the system tray that UAC is off. You do not need to restart UAC so click whichever option you need to to ignore the reminder. But better to turn the (really annoying) reminders off.
Click on Start > Control Panel. Click the Security tab, followed by Security Centre.
On the left-hand side of the new window, click Change the way Security Center alerts me.
If you want no notification at all, select the bottom option: Don’t notify me and don’t display the icon. Otherwise, use Don’t notify me, but display the icon.